# Typescript types, property exist on this type, but other type not [ CLOSED ]

Tags: typescript

Function Def

```
async findUser(name: string): Promise<User | Error> {
  const user = await this.model.findOne({
    username: name,
  });
  if (!user) throw new Error('Username not found!');
  else if (user) {
    return user;
  }
}
```

Calling the function

```
async validateUser(username: string, password: string): Promise<any> {
  const user = await this.userService.findUser(username);
  if (user) {
    const compare = await Compare(password, user.password)
  }
}
```

[image: Error]

#### Error explained

I want the function return the `User` object, if it doesn't exist then return a `Error` object, but typescript check property `password` for both Types `User` and `Error`.

**Is there anyway to make typescript ignore this error and only check for the `User`?**

#### SOLVED!!

```
try {
  if(!user) throw new Error('Username not found!');
} finally {
  return user;
}
```

Comment: Please provide a [mre] that clearly demonstrates the issue you are facing.  Ideally someone could paste the code into a standalone IDE like [The TypeScript Playground (link here!)](https://tsplay.dev/wXK41W) and immediately get to work solving the problem without first needing to re-create it.  So there should be no pseudocode, typos, unrelated errors, or undeclared types or values.

Comment: [Please replace/supplement images of code/errors with plaintext versions.](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/285557/2887218)

Comment: Why does your function (have a type annotation to) return a promise that resolves to a user or error? When you throw an error in an async function, it doesn't return an error. It rejects the promise with the error.